# Assigning an array formula to a variable in a array that is used in a loop

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, variables

Could anyone help me out with the following query I have.

I am trying to assign an array formula to the b3 variable and cannot get this to work. I have previously used .formulaarray in specific cell instances in other pieces of script that I have written however I would like to know how to assign an arrayformula to the variable within the code below.

b3 = "=if($C$" & OffsetValue - 1 & "=C$" & OffsetValue - 1 & ",PRODUCT(1+$C" & OffsetValue + 1 + i & ":C$" & OffsetValue + 1 + i & ")-1,C$" & OffsetValue + 1 + i & ")"

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

```
Sub performancefees()

            Dim i As Integer
            Dim f As Range, rng As Range
            Dim wb As Workbook
            Dim ws As Worksheet, CtrlWs As Worksheet
            Dim fund As String
            Dim offset As Integer
            Dim ModelStart As Date, ModelEnd As Date
            'Dim a As variable



            OffsetValue = 10
            i = 1
            Set rng = Range("Funds")
            Sheets("FeeCalc").Activate

                        CtrlSheet = "Control"
                Set CtrlWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CtrlSheet)
                    ModelStart = CtrlWs.Range("C3")
                    ModelEnd = CtrlWs.Range("C4")


            For Each f In rng
            Dim calc
            b1 = "=INDEX(INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & " &""_Financials""),MATCH(""Total unitholders' funds"",INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & "&""_Financials_Desc""),0),MATCH(EOMONTH(C$" & OffsetValue & " ,0),INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & "&""_Financials_Timeline""),0))"
            b2 = "= " & f & "_Benchmark/12"
            b3 = "=if($C$" & OffsetValue - 1 & "=C$" & OffsetValue - 1 & ",PRODUCT(1+$C" & OffsetValue + 1 + i & ":C$" & OffsetValue + 1 + i & ")-1,C$" & OffsetValue + 1 + i & ")"
            b4 = "=INDEX(INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & " &""_Financials""),MATCH(""Fund Total Return (post base management fee)"",INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & "&""_Financials_Desc""),0),MATCH(EOMONTH(C$" & OffsetValue & " ,0),INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & "&""_Financials_Timeline""),0))"
            b5 = ""
            b6 = "=(C" & OffsetValue + 3 + i & "-C" & OffsetValue + 1 + i & ")*C" & OffsetValue + i & " "
            b7 = "=(C" & OffsetValue + 4 + i & "-C" & OffsetValue + 2 + i & ")*C" & OffsetValue + i & " "
            b8 = "=INDEX(INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & " &""_Financials""),MATCH(""Management fee"",INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & "&""_Financials_Desc""),0),MATCH(EOMONTH(C$" & OffsetValue & " ,0),INDIRECT($A" & OffsetValue + i & "&""_Financials_Timeline""),0))"
            b9 = "=C" & OffsetValue + i & "*" & f & "_PFValCap"
            b10 = "=min(C" & OffsetValue + 7 + i & ",C" & OffsetValue + 8 + i & "-C" & OffsetValue + 7 + i & ")"
            b11 = "=C" & OffsetValue + 6 + i & "*" & f & "_PerfFee"
            b12 = "Minimum Fund Performance Satisfied?"
            b13 = "Performance Fee Cap Applies?"
            b14 = "Actual Capped PF"

            For Each calc In Array(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13, b14)
            f = f
                    Range(Cells(OffsetValue + i, 3), Cells(OffsetValue + i, LastColumn)) = Array(calc)
                    i = i + 1
            Next calc
            Next f



            End Sub
```

Comment: `= calc` not `= Array(calc)`

Comment: Thanks for that, that was a left over piece of the code before it was changed. However that still does not fix my problem.

Comment: I cant understand why I am being downvoted? I have researched this and found no answer and therefore have come to the community. If my post was hard to understand, noone has left any feedback saying so.

Comment: It usually helps to explain what is going wrong when you run your code. Do you get an error?  If Yes what is the error and on which line? If you're having a problem assigning a formula then use Debug.Print to output it to the Immediate pane, then try copy/pasting it to the worksheet and see what error you get.

Comment: Sorry about that. There is no actual error message error that is coming through. The problem I am having is that the formula is coming through as =IF($C$9=C$9,PRODUCT(1+$C12:C$12)-1,C$12) instead of an array formula {=IF($C$9=C$9,PRODUCT(1+$C12:C$12)-1,C$12)}

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `.Formula` property to assign your regular formulas, but if you want to set an array formula then you should use the cell's `.FormulaArray` property.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formulaarray-property-excel

Comment: Thanks Tim, how would I associate this to b3. Would this be b3.FormulaArray. When I do this I get a run time error '424': Object Required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simplified version showing how to switch one of your formulas into an array formula:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim calcs(1 To 5)

    calcs(1) = "=A9"
    calcs(2) = "=B9"
    calcs(3) = "=C9"
    calcs(4) = "=D9"
    calcs(5) = "Just a header"

    With Range("A10").Resize(1, UBound(calcs))
        .Formula = calcs
        'make the third formula into an array formula
        .Cells(3).FormulaArray = .Cells(3).Formula
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much Tim, I should be able to run with that.